# Applying filter and calculating Average on NSDictionary with JSON origin

Tags: ios, swift, filter, nsarray, nsdictionary

I read some posts here and google about it, but still couldn't understand how to do a simple filter using the swift filter feature. I am new to Swift and functional programing, so forgive me if that is too basic.

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "-KjirKH7Bo7c5vq7ZH9N" =     {
        rank = 2;
        placa = "xxx-0003";
        uid = yNpL0uzI5LRj6etFGVgoWYEK2E52;
    };
    "-Kjiyi_i7FLl6dks6xKL" =     {
        rank = 5;
        placa = "xxx-0003";
        uid = yNpL0uzI5LRj6etFGVgoWYEK2E52;
    };
}
```

I was able to create an array of the values with:

```
 if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
                let myArray = dict.map{$0.value} //array of values
             }
```

Which creates this:

```
    [{
    rank = 5;
    placa = "xxx-0003";
    uid = yNpL0uzI5LRj6etFGVgoWYEK2E52;
}, {
    rank = 2;
    placa = "xxx-0003";
    uid = yNpL0uzI5LRj6etFGVgoWYEK2E52;
}]
```

My goal now is:

Apply a filter to retrieve only items that the property "rank" is greater than 0.
After that I want to calculate the items rank average (in this example 2+5/2 = 3.5).

I have tried this:

```
myArray.filter{$0.rank > 0 }
```

But it fails with "Value of type 'Any' has no member 'rank'"

Any idea how I can filter this array?
I have tried with NSPredicate, but I am wondering if there is some way to take advantage of the native filter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two issues:

1. myArray's items are of type `Any` and in reality they are dictionaries so you have to help compiler to understand that. Here is how to do it:

`let myArray: [[String: Any]] = dict.map{ $0.value }`

2. Because `myArray` contains dictionaries, you have to modify accessing values in filter:

`myArray.filter{ (($0["rank"] as? Int) ?? 0) > 0 }`

Hope it helps!

Comment: for the item 1, I got:  Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to closure result type '[String : Any]'

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray.filter{ ((($0 as! NSDictionary)["rank"] as? Int) ?? 0) > 0 }
```

appending the answer of K.K Cast $0 to NSDictionary. I hope that will work

Comment: Didn't work also, it returns an empty array. I think I will have to create a struct to organize it